# how to execute windows shell .bat file to replace some number in json file with another number

Tags: shell, execute

here you are the example some times the values go random like "0.6000" "0.7000" "0.8000"
i want to change any number inside quotes ( Random ) for the specific field name up them "NativeOffsetX" and "NativeOffsetY" to 0
thanks in advance for the help and i appericate your time and help sir <3[image]